# "bundle exec rake" doesn't honor "without"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, bundler, gitlab-ci

On a GitLab installation from source, I'm having problems running binaries such as `rake`. I've never seen similar problems with my own Ruby or Rails projects:

```
# bundle config
Set for your local app (/mnt/data/www/gitlab.bitcetera.com/source/gitlab/.bundle/config): "1"

path
Set for your local app (/mnt/data/www/gitlab.bitcetera.com/source/gitlab/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"

without
Set for your local app (/mnt/data/www/gitlab.bitcetera.com/source/gitlab/.bundle/config): "development:test:unicorn:mysql:kerberos:metrics"

disable_shared_gems
Set for your local app (/mnt/data/www/gitlab.bitcetera.com/source/gitlab/.bundle/config): "true"

# bundle install --deployment --without development test unicorn mysql kerberos metrics
# bundle config
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied

# bundle exec rake --tasks
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- haml_lint/rake_task
```

Looking at the relevant section of the [Gemfile](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v9.3.5/Gemfile#L336):

```
group :development, :test do
  [...]
  gem 'haml_lint', '~> 0.21.0', require: false
  [...]
end
```

Of course the `haml_lint` gem is missing, after all, it's in the "development" and "test" groups only which I've excluded by "without".

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, kinda daft reason: RAILS_ENV should have been set automatically yet it wasn't so of course things go awry.

Comment: This makes sense except for the part where `RAILS_ENV` should be set automatically. There's no reason why `bundle exec` or `rake` on their own would set the value; its default value is initialized by either [`rails server`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/111736ddf6fe81f3e42af37dfa1b0520a8c91473/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb#L33-L35) or `rails console` (similar implementation). If you want your rake task to target an environment then the task should implement a sane default.